# Change preformatted text into javascript object

Tags: javascript, jenkins, eslint

I have the following ESLint result which was fetched from Jenkins.

```
> todo@0.1.0 eslint /path/to/the/workspace
> eslint src/components/** src/page/**

Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .

/some/path/to/my/file1.js
  12:11  error  'placeholder' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  12:24  error  'event' is missing in props validation        react/prop-types

/some/path/to/my/file2.js
  17:11  error  'title' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  17:18  error  'subtitle' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  21:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  22:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  23:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  24:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  25:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  26:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  27:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs

/some/path/to/my/file3.js
  14:11  error  'items' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
  14:18  error  'remove' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  19:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  19:14  error  'items.map' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  20:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  21:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  22:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  23:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  24:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  25:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  26:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  27:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  28:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  29:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  30:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  31:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  32:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs

/some/path/to/my/file4.js
  19:14  error  'props' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 29 problems (29 errors, 0 warnings)
```

But i want to display this in a much meaningful way... something like inside a html box, with a header showing the project name (which is the name of the workspace). Then a list of accordion for every linting result for every file, and at the bottom of the box, it will display the total errors.

But for me to do that, i need to be able to convert the returned result into a  meaningful object that i could manipulate and iterate. Something like below

```
{
  projectname: 'Project Name',
  totalErrors: 29,
  totalWarnings: 0,
  result: [
    {
      file: '/some/path/to/my/file1.js',
      error: [
        { line: 12, column: 11, type: "react/proptypes", description: "'placeholder' is missing in props validation" },
        { line: 12, column: 11, type: "react/proptypes", description: "'placeholder' is missing in props validation" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this? To convert the preformatted text from Jenkins into an object that i can manipulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible you just have to define what property keys should go with which columns, after seperating them. For example, first you need to seperate each line by splitting by "\n", then you need to split by the last column which is spaced by "                      ", then split by the string "error  ", etc.. let's take it one step at a time. Say your Jenkins string is in a variable called jenk, then just do the following:

```js
var jenk = `
Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .

/some/path/to/my/file1.js
  12:11  error  'placeholder' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  12:24  error  'event' is missing in props validation        react/prop-types

/some/path/to/my/file2.js
  17:11  error  'title' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  17:18  error  'subtitle' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  21:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  22:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  23:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  24:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  25:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  26:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  27:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                      no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs

/some/path/to/my/file3.js
  14:11  error  'items' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
  14:18  error  'remove' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  19:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  19:14  error  'items.map' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  20:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  21:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  22:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  23:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  24:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  25:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  26:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  27:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  28:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  29:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  30:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  31:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
  32:2   error  Mixed spaces and tabs                       no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs

/some/path/to/my/file4.js
  19:14  error  'props' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
`,
 f = jenk.split("\n").map(x=>x.split("  ")),
    h = f.flat().flat(),
    j = h.filter(x => x.length > 0).map(x => x.trim());
 


var cur = null,
    newA = {};
j.forEach(x => {
    if(x[0] == "/") {
        cur = x;
        newA[cur] = [];
    } else {
        if(cur && newA[cur]) {
            newA[cur].push(x)
        }
    }
})


var newB = []
for(var k in newA) {
    newB.push({
        file: k,
        error:[]
    });
    var i,a,temparray,chunk = 4;
    for (i=0,a=newA[k].length; i<a; i+=chunk) {
        temparray = newA[k].slice(i,i+chunk);
        newB[newB.length-1].error.push(temparray)
    }
    newB[newB.length-1].error = newB[newB.length-1].error.map(x => (
        {
            line: x[0].split(":")[0],
            column: x[0].split(":")[1],
            type: x[3],
            description: x[2]
        }
    ))
}

console.log("Your JSON Object: ", newB);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can parse the output string to json like bluejayke's answer said. However, if you could change the eslint configuration, you can make eslint output json immediately and turn it to whatever format you want.

```
eslint -f json [your files]
```

reference: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#f-format